# Is there a way to set the axis level on a Google Sheets win loss sparkline to a figure in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet which has 2 tabs, the first is called **Data** and the second is called **Dashboard**.

I want a Win Loss sparkline in a cell on the sheet titled **Dashboard**.

The axis level is set to **0** as a standard on sparklines but I would like this to be set to the figure based in cell **U3** on the **Data** tab.

The sparkline itself should auto update daily to always show the past 30 days. The dates are in **B4:B368** on my **Data** tab and the figures needed for the past 30 days are in **U4:U368**.

```
=SPARKLINE((indirect("Data!U"&match(today()-30, Data!B:B, true)): indirect("Data!U"&match(today(), Data!B:B, true))),{"charttype","winloss";"color","blue";"axis",true;"axiscolor","black";"firstcolor","grey";"lastcolor","pink"})
```

I've come up with the above formula but so far not having any luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rd4U9iCQq64afi1yaZgucO98RbN1INDTaaoa0slEIVU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a fix by adding an additional column and applying this formula in that new column.

```
=ArrayFormula((U4:U368-U3)*-1)
```

I then set my win/loss sparkline to this column.

This formula balances out the win/loss by removing the target figure based in cell U3 which then allows me to adjust the sparkline X axis.

Answer (score 0):

The available options for `SPARKLINE` can be found [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289#:%7E:text=For%20column%20and%20winloss%20sparklines). Some options like `ymin` and `ymax` that defines min and max value along the axis are not applicable for "winloss" charts.